# Is there a way around the double If Statement for .IsNullOrEmpty() and then .Trim()? (more details inside)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

So let's say you have a string and you want to check for null/empty.  You also want to check for empty string.  The only way I know how to do this (below) is to first check for null AND THEN check for empty string.  If you do the .Trim() before checking for null, and there is a null, then you have an error.

I really don't like having to use two separate If Statements.  Is there a way around this?

Example:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strMyVariable)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strMyVariable.Trim()))
   {
      //the variable is not null, empty, or contain an empty string
      //so you can now (finally!) do something with it.
   }
}
```

Comment: For the second if statement, you don't need to check for nulls. just `strMyVariable.Trim() != string.Empty` is enough. You can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to combine both.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strMyVariable))
{

}
```

Quoting from the MSDN reference:

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.